# is django superuser bad for security?

Tags: django

is django superuser bad for security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No?  What makes you think it is?

Comment: From reading the install instructions for certain applications. Some say do not create a superuser, so I was wondering if it was a security issue.

Comment: simply create a superuser with a strong password, this allows you to acces the admin